# How to get string from jquery children method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$item
<div><p>adfadf</p><p>adfadf</p></div>

$item.children()
[<p>​adfadf​</p>​, <p>​adfadf​</p>​]

$item.children().toString()
"[object Object]"

$item.children().text()
"adfadfadfadf"

$item.children().prop('outerHTML')
"<p>adfadf</p>"
```

i want the output to be `"<p>​adfadf​</p>​<p>​adfadf​</p>"`.
"outerHTML" is working but it is returning only one node data in string 
how to get all the children data in string ?

Comment: please provide your html also.

Comment: @AnkitKathiriya updated with html

Comment: use jsue $item.html() method

Comment: @AnkitKathiriya thanks it worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why not simply

```
$item.html();
```

or

```
var html = "";
$item.children().each( function(){

  html += $( this ).prop('outerHTML');

} );
console.log( html );
```